# how is the Y plane from YUV is saved in byte array

Tags: java, android, yuv

I am using camera 2 API to take images

I need only the brightness of the images so I use the y buffer only as below

```
      ByteBuffer buffer = image.getPlanes()[0].getBuffer();

                byte[] bytes = new byte[buffer.capacity()];

                buffer.get(bytes);
```

as far as i know the y plane has all the image pixels and each value of pixel brightness is stored in the byte array value, whats the sequnce they are stored in ? 
for example is image is like this :

```
xxxxx
yyyyy
zzzzz
```

then the bytes array would be like [xxxxyyyyyzzzzz] or [xyzxyzxyzxyz]  ?

I tried both sequence but I keep getting wrong results also when I try different phones I get different results ? 
while the resolution is fixed the image format is YUV_420 
the images that I use are only black or white !

Comment: Did you find a solution? I am having the same problem.